# Conan: aggregate multiple packages to be used indepentendly

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I am currently using Conan as an "helper tool" for my main project: I have created a conanfile.py that builds all my dependencies and imports them to the current folder. The goal in the end is to archive and redistribute this folder to our multiple machines and just tell CMake that everything is in there.

However, here's the catch: I want this archive to not be dependent on Conan. Our CMakeLists.txt are using Find_Package() and I really want this to work non intrusively. So far, I have managed to get something working, *however*, my main problem is CMake integration.

Here's how I want to create my archive:

```sh
mkdir build
conan install <path to my conanfile> -if build
tar cf archive.tar build
```

So far, I have managed to properly copy all my dependencies in the correct directories (build/bin contains all binaries, build/include all includes and so on)

My only problem now is using CMake. I tried using cmake_paths and cmake_find_package generators but **they all point to the conan cache on my machine**.

I then tried the deploy generator, which seems to be very close to what I want to achieve. However, I cannot figure out how to generate cmake files from the directory I just deployed to.

I found the generate() method but I havent had much success with it.

Do I need to implement this externally ? Like patching the files created by the cmake generators ? Or is there a cleaner way ?

Thanks

Edit: Just want to clarify: I do not want to use conan for anything else than simply building my dependencies. It is installed on our main server that hosts the gitlab CI/CD that will build the binaries. It is not used by anything else.

Comment: Yes, if you extract all the dependencies to a different location, via imports/deploys or manually, those files are no longer Conan packages. This is not an issue for deploying (dlls, executables), or if your build system knows to consumer bare libraries. But you are missing all the information that Conan is providing you. I'd recommend for development leave the packages in the cache, and extract the exes and shared libs and data for deployment outside Conan

Comment: @drodri Yes, that I understand. But for development, I often need to build the software on new machines. I do not want to install conan and setup all my packages again (we do not have a remote. I am just using conan to build the archive).

I am just trying to find a way to generate the cmake Config files **after** deploying. 

Now that I think about it, it's quite the equivalent of calling ``cmake install <build>`` on the dependencies... Maybe that's a possibility ?

Comment: @drodri It's just very frustrating because this seems like a reasonable need from users and I feel like I am so close of getting it working, I feel like I'm just missing one tiny bit of insight.

Also; I am using Conan strictly to build the archive every once in a while. I do not mind having to re-build packages if it is necessary.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to share the built dependencies so other build machines don't have to rebuild them?

Comment: @John Yes! Conan just seemed to be a very good tool for that as I want to be able to specify specific versions and options.

Comment: @jackylamouette And you want Conan to be able to do this for you?

Comment: @John well.. that's kinda what my question is about. I can elaborate on a specific point if I was not clear? But yeah, I have pretty much almost got something working, I managed to build and package everything with my conanfiles, my only problem now is getting the cmake generator to understand that I do not want to use the cached libraries but the one I just copied.

Comment: @jackylamouette If you want Conan to do it for you, its called a Conan remote.  If you want CMake to do it for you, you have to install them where CMake looks for them.

Comment: @John I mean, cmake generator practically does what I want. It seems possible to achieve my goal from this position. I don't see what having a remote would change, the deployment would be the same if I fetched packages directly from the remote. This is not very helpful ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered by Conan's co-founder james here: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/9874

Basically:

- Use the CMakeDeps generator instead of cmake / cmake_find_package
- Patch the resulting cmake config files at install time inside the generate() method from the main conanfile.py
- Edit recipes accordingly (but should be fine most of the time)